# Change Actionlink parameter from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a textbox to select Date and there is one action link in the razor page to redirect to another page with date value as one of the parameter.
Is there any way to dynamically change the value of actionlink whenever a user change the date.
My Razor view is like

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new { @class = "datepicker form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
</div>
@Html.ActionLink("Mark Attendance", "Add", "Attendance", new { @id = @model.ClassId }, new { @class = " btn btn-primary"})
```

And in Javascript i have been able to do

```
$("#Date").datepicker({
  showOn: 'both',
  altFormat: 'MM-dd-yy',
  dateFormat: 'MM-dd-yy',
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  yearRange: "1900:2050"
})
  .change(dateChanged)
  .on('changeDate', dateChanged);

function dateChanged(ev) {
  //How can i change the action link in a way that add an extra param date with selected value ?
}
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Whats the signature of the action method (name of the parameter)?

Comment: Date like Attendance/Add?id=model.id&date=<mydatevalue>

Answer (score 4):

You can change the value of date using javascript

```
$('.btn btn-primary').attr('href', function () {
        return this.href.replace('_Parameter1', Date_Value);
          });
```

In View:-

```
@Html.ActionLink("Mark Attendance", "Add", "Attendance", new { @id = @model.ClassId,Parameter1='_Parameter1'}, new { @class = " btn btn-primary"})
```

In Controller:-

```
public ActionResult Add(int ID, DateTime date)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can update the links href attribute using

```
var url = $('#mylink').attr('href'); // returns "Attendance/Add/1"
function dateChanged(ev) {
  $('#mylink').attr('href', url + '?date=' + <mydatevalue>);
}
```

note this assumes you give the link an id

```
@Html.ActionLink("Mark Attendance", "Add", "Attendance", new { id = @Model.ClassId }, new { @class = " btn btn-primary", new id = "mylink" })
```

which would redirect to

```
public ActionResult Add(int ID, DateTime date)
```